# How can I center the "input" tag in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to customize "input" in CSS this is code I write:

```
  input {
    background-color:black;
    border-color: blueviolet;
    outline-color:peru;
    color: crimson;
    height: 50px;
}
```

And I want to put the "input" tag in the middle.

I tried:

```
text-align: center;
```

but didn't work

Comment: "In the middle" of what?  `text-align: center;` would center the text within that element.  Is that not what you want?  Please update this to include relevant HTML as a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What I wrote in HTML is just: <input type="type">
I am trying to move the writable area created by the "input" tag to the center of the screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way you can center an element in its parent container is by making it `display: block` and setting the margin to `auto`:

```css
input {
    background-color:black;
    border-color: blueviolet;
    outline-color:peru;
    color: crimson;
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Another could be by using flex-box styling:

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

input {
    background-color:black;
    border-color: blueviolet;
    outline-color:peru;
    color: crimson;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: Yes, what I'm looking for is the first code block you wrote.
"display: block" and "margin: auto;"